# SQS recieveMessage or polling not woriking in an infinite loop NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am basically playing around with aws sqs and I want to establish an infinite connection for polling messages. But my function sqs.recieveMessage is not bieng called in an infinite loop. Can anybody help me with this. My piece of code and paramteres are as follows:

```
recieveMessageParams: {
            AttributeNames: [
                "SentTimestamp"
            ],
            MaxNumberOfMessages: 1,
            MessageAttributeNames: [
                "All"
            ],
            QueueUrl: queueURL,
            VisibilityTimeout: 43195,
            WaitTimeSeconds: 20
        }
```

```
function sqsReceivemessage(params) {
  while(true) {
    sqs.receiveMessage(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Receive Error", err);
        return err;
      } else if (data) {
        console.log("data recieved")
        let body = JSON.parse(data?.Messages[0].Body);
        let action = data?.Messages[0].MessageAttributes?.action?.StringValue;
        if(action === 'vaxxaEmailAttemptToSend'){
          vaxxaEmailAttemptToSend(body);
        }
        let deleteParams = {
          QueueUrl: queueURL,
          ReceiptHandle: data.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle
        };
        sqs.deleteMessage(deleteParams, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Delete Error", err);
            return err;
          } else {
            console.log("Message Deleted", data);
            return data;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is anything calling the `sqsReceivemessage()` function?

Comment: Yes I have a controller which recieves an api request and above mentioned sqsReceivemessage() function is written in service file which is bieng called in result of that controler function.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code layout would benefit from a re-architecture to a Lambda which would also help reduce the amount of bug probable code and make it easier to isolate code issues:

- I recommend doing this as [a lambda instead](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-example.html) as it handles the polling for you and automatically deletes the messages from the queue for you if the lambda returns a success. This will reduce the overall code you're working with and help better isolate if it's a queue delivery or code issue.
- I notice you're attempting to send email. Do note that unless you're accessing a web API to do it, both Lambda and EC2 [restrict outgoing port 25](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle) so you may need to deal with that. If you're trying to send something like an admin email than using SNS subscriptions might be a better way.